# android studio invokeCommomQuizActivity

Tags: java, android, listview, menuitem

вот мой код когда я нажму кнопке приложение улетает

```
package uz.ascending.uzquiz.utilities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import uz.ascending.uzquiz.constants.AppConstants;

public class ActivityUtilities {
    private static ActivityUtilities activityUtilities = null;

    public static ActivityUtilities getInstance() {
        if (activityUtilities == null) {
            activityUtilities = new ActivityUtilities();
        }
        return activityUtilities;
    }

    public void invokeNewActivity(Activity activity, Class<?> tClass, boolean shoulgFinish) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, tClass);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        if (shoulgFinish) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

    public void invokeCustomUrlActivity(Activity activity, Class<?> tclass, String pageTitle, String pageUrl, boolean shouldfinish) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, tclass);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_TITLE, pageTitle);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_URL, pageUrl);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        if (shouldfinish) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

    public void invokeCommonQuizActivity(Activity activity, Class<?> tClass, String categoryId, boolean shouldFinish) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, tClass);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.BUNDLE_KEY_INDEX, categoryId);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        if (shouldFinish) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

ошибка run

```
**E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: uz.ascending.uzquiz, PID: 19701
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {uz.ascending.uzquiz/uz.ascending.uzquiz.activity.QuizPromptActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2074)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1720)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5258)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5203)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5587)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5555)
        at uz.ascending.uzquiz.utilities.ActivityUtilities.invokeCommonQuizActivity(ActivityUtilities.java:39)
        at uz.ascending.uzquiz.activity.MainActivity$3.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:224)
        at uz.ascending.uzquiz.adapters.CategoryAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(CategoryAdapter.java:124)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7862)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7831)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:879)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29359)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19701 SIG: 9
**
```

Comment: во время `улёта` смотрите в вкладку logcat будет причина красным текстом выделена, если не разберетесь то в вопрос вставьте

Comment: посмотрите ошибка

Comment: у вас QuizPromptActivity есть в манифесте? в ошибке говорится что у вас неизвестная активность вызывается

Comment: нет в манифесте

Comment: <activity android:name=".activity.AboutDevActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.CustomUrlActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.BaseActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity">

Comment: как так добавить надо

Comment: например добавьте строку `<activity android:name=".QuizPromptActivity" >` вот тут рассказано как добавить активность в манифест https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870202/how-to-add-activity-to-manifest-xml-in-right-way

Comment: спасибо большое работает